# How to configure multiple table rate and multiple type shipping in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, shipping, payment-methods, table-rates

I am using Magento 2.0.2 and I'd like to configure multiple table rates with multiple types of shipping. Please see my shipping options below

[image]

If you have any suggestion or any free extension that will be really helpfull.
Thank you!